# Error on converting String to Date

Tags: date, reporting-services

My date data looks like this: 20151112,20151116 .I want to convert it into Date "MM/DD/YYYY", then i used the Code:

```
=CDATE(MID(Fields!Date.Value,5,2)&"/"&(RIGHT(Fields!Date.Value,2)&"/"&LEFT(Fields!Date.Value,4)))
```

But there is an Error: Conversion from String 11/24/2015 to type Date is invalid. Can you please help me how to fix this Problem?

Comment: Sorry, i forget to say, im working in SSRS

Comment: What is the data source?  can you convert it in your query to a date data type?

Comment: @phalondon Tag your Question with the programming language in use.

Answer (score 0):

You are making your life harder than it needs to be by converting your string date into a potentially ambiguous localised date format (`MM/dd/yyyy`) and *then* trying to actually convert it to a `date` datatype. If you go about this the other way around - converting your data to a `date` data type *and then* formatting it - you will avoid a lot of headaches.

To do this, you need to first add in some forward slashes `/` to your string dates, retaining the `yyyy/MM/dd`:

`=CDate(left("20160131",4) & "/" & mid("20160131",5,2) & "/" & right("20160131",2))`

Now that you have a `date` data type that will always be properly handled by SSRS, you can format it however you require for being displayed in your application:

`=format(CDate(left("20160131",4) & "/" & mid("20160131",5,2) & "/" & right("20160131",2)),"MM/dd/yyyy")`